# find the mean for points of binary features

Tags: math, binary, data-mining, binary-data, mean

I have groups of binary string each bit represent a feature in a variable e.g I have a color variable where red blue and green are the features thus if I have 010 --> I have a blue object.

I need to get the center of these objects by calculating a weighted mean example 010 weight's 0.5; 100 weights 0.4 and 001 weights 0.8 [010 *0.5 + 100*0.4 + 001*0.8]/[1.7]

is there a possibility to get a point which represents the center of those points which should had same properties of others points (binary on 3 bits)

thank u in advance for your help

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve, but is it as simple as follows (using your example):

[010 * .5 + 100 * .4 + 001 * .8]/1.7 = 3.4/1.7 = 2 = 010.
So 010 would be the "center" point (in a linear, weighted average sense) in this case.

If you ended up with a fractional value, you'd round to integer then convert to binary. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use the following approach from cluster analysis: you need to choose metric for your object space (Euclidean, Taxicab or something else) and then for all objects from group (or if cardinality of the set is small - for all possible objects) calculate average distance to all objects from group. Then, you can assume object with a smallest average distance is center of a group.